# Force a form to send in UTF8 to my MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, dreamweaver

I'm designing the backend of a web with dreamweaver and MySQL. When I send a form, the content is weird (Like Áa(C)) and not show de correct charset. I put the charset utf8 in the header  (in the php and html too), and tried with utf8_encode in each POST. But still don't work... anyone knows something? That characters are shown too in the MySQL (and even it's utf8). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also: http://kunststube.net/frontback

Answer (score 0):

use

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

in your php file

Comment: Thanks! But, it doesn't work :S this appears really weird because it works sometimes and other times not...